# NCache with Entity Framework 6.1 not working with NCache API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ncache

Using NCache 4.6 with EF 6.1.3, can't make it to work with NCache API.

It works when using query policy inside `efcaching.ncconf` but using only `api-level-caching` and `.Cache()` method, have no effect in caching.

Steps that I've taken:

Added `Alachisoft.Integrations.EntityFramework.CachingProvider` refrence to project.

Added interceptor:

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor type="Alachisoft.NCache.Integrations.EntityFramework.Caching.EFCommandInterceptor, Alachisoft.Integrations.EntityFramework.CachingProvider" />
</interceptors>
```

Added `Alachisoft.NCache.Integrations.EntityFramework.Caching` namespace to file.

And finally, using their `EntityDataModel` sample, for example, changed `PrintCustomerList(customerQuery);` to `PrintCustomerList(customerQuery.Cache());`, but result is not cached.

**UPDATE 1:**

Checking with `dumpcachekeys.exe`, it has actually created cache for my queries, but still it goes to database for results.

**UPDATE 2:**

Trying to dump cash data with `dumpcachedata.exe` fails with following error:

```
Items in cache      : 3

Error: Failed to resolve assembly: EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
System.Exception: Failed to resolve assembly: EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityDataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          
    at Alachisoft.NCache.Tools.DumpCacheData.DumpCacheData.MakeBackup(Cache cache, String path)
    at Alachisoft.NCache.Tools.DumpCacheData.DumpCacheData.Run(String[] args)
```

**UPDATE 3**

Disabling dynamic proxy in entity framework for `EntityDataModel` sample, solved error thrown in `dumpcachedata.exe`, and now cash data successfully dumps. But still cached queries cause database trip.

Comment: Has your problem been solved ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915095/ncache-as-entity-framework-second-level-cache-not-syncing-with-database/38085159#38085159

Comment: @BasitAnwer, just checked, same problem